# module.exports = ({}) vs {}

Tags: node.js, koa-router, module.exports

I work with Koa middleware and in some code I use this code in router:

```
module.exports = ({router}) => {
//some code
}
```

if I do:

```
module.exports = {router} => {
//some code
}
```

the nodejs app throws an error. So whats the difference between these two different exports except the error part?

Comment: `{(router)}` seems odd, shouldn't it be `({router})`?

Comment: actually yes its like "({router})" this. sorry about that

Comment: Whenever you write "throws an error" you should **really** post the actual error message in the question.

Answer (score 0):

{(router)} is just wrong. You should see module.exports as a function so it has () where the arguments go, which in this case is an object {} of the functions you want to export (here router, but it could be multiple just as well.

I think this article gives a very clear explanation: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/